# What's the best practice to deploy (manage dependency) the django reusable apps in a real production project?

Tags: django, deployment, reusability

In our project we are using some django reusable apps, we are considering how to make the continuous and automatic deployment easy and painless.

We have 2 options:

option#1: use "pip install xxx" to install all dependencies reusable apps.  Write a script to install and check the dependencies.

option#2: make a copy of all used reusable apps under our own directory, so we basically will deploy everything in our project directory.

both options have its pros and cons, I am wondering if you can share your the best practice of doing this?

Comment: Recommended: http://blip.tv/djangocon/taming-dependencies-with-pip-5582996

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can create a file of dependencies with `pip` very easily which will mean that the correct versions of each app will be maintained between servers

```
# Save dependancies to a file
pip freeze > requirement_file.txt
```

creates a file something like:

```
django==1.3
django-tagging
markdown
...
```

which can be later used to reinstall the listed apps on a different server

```
# Install all dependencies in the file
pip install -r requirement_file.txt
```

This is a nice and simple approach. You can get more complicated with the likes of zc.buildout

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zc.buildout

which helps manage packages (python and non-python) via scripts (you create 'recipes' containing the details of the packages you need installed)

If you need broader control over server installs you could use 'puppet' or 'chef'

http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/1/wiki/Big_Picture
http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Chef+Server

which are aimed at automating and deploying more than just dependencies, but entire servers

I haven't needed to use more then simple pip requirements files, but the other options are great if you need more.

**EDIT**

Keeping your own version of the apps in your project root/python path can become cumbersome and difficult to track, I'd suggest using a pip requirement file.

Answer (score 0):

I found one in django's website:

https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/best-practices-to-work-with-3rd-party-apps-and-making-yours-portable

Looks like he is suggesting what I listed in question as option #2.

Comment: I do like keeping them in a local directory, so that I can easily modify them as needed and everything is in one place when moved.